# Running .py file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple code done in Jupyter Notebook that extracts data from a tsv file, uses it in another dataframe and exports it to a csv file.
When running in Jupyter notebook it works perfectly, but if i save as a .py file and run it inside windows it doesnt work.

My objective is make the .py file work to schedule it to run daily.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\quadr\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\2004-2019.tsv", engine='python',delimiter='\t',encoding='utf8')
df2 = df.iloc[:,3:6]
df2.to_csv("C:\\Users\\quadr\\OneDrive\\Área de Trabalho\\teste.csv")
```

Comment: Can you please clarify a little bit? Why it is not working? What error do you get, etc..?

Comment: must be due to environment issue

Comment: When i run the .py file it doesn't show any errors. It runs, the command prompt shows up and closes. But nothing happens. It should create a csv file in my desktop but it doesn't. I'm assuming its because anaconda environment in jupyter notebook is set up properly and in my pc it isn't. But i dont know how to do that

Comment: Can you try to run it from a command prompt instead? That should show what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to make sure windows feeds the .py to the correct python installation.
The task you need to schedule on windows will be

```
(Path To)python.exe (Path To Your .py)
```

Where you replace stuff in parentheses with the appropriate paths.  Check if python is in your path by running

```
where python.exe
```

If it found it and it's the intended installation, version, etc, you can do without the (Path To) portion before python.exe.  if you can't find where python.exe resides installed after searching, you may just need to install python (and any addons) and explicitly point to this new install.

Next things to check are that the directories you are writing to exist and the files you are reading from exist.

Comment: Ok, but if the script is not running correctly as it is, scheduling it is not very useful.

Comment: Agreed.  Need to know what in "run it inside windows it doesnt work," the "run it" method is to help debug why "it doesn't work."  My appologies for assuming it was the scheduler and not the command prompt or some other method.